# iOS/xcode/objective-c: How to instantiate view controller after signup

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, window

After a successful sign up, I want users to go through a process where they provide photo etc.  Similar code to that below worked to load the login page but code below is not working to load a separate view controller in storyboard "newuser".

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix.

```
- (void)presentNewUserInterface
{
    UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newuser"];
    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
- (void)presentNewUserInterface
{
    UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newuser"];
    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;     
}
```

Try:

```
- (void)presentNewUserInterface
{
    UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newuser"];
    UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

You aren't presenting your new navigation controller in your example. Is there a particular reason why you would be trying to replace your rootViewController? That shouldn't be needed. My example should be sufficient for displaying your next flow in the user sign up process.

Comment: Hi, that code worked for the next step in sign up.  However when I tried to use identical code to segue to third step, (i.e. I just changed the name of the storyboard id to another VC) it loaded the third VC but then none of the buttons or anything are active.  (This VC is also accessible from another part of the app so I know it works fine otherwise.)  Do I have to modify this to launch 3rd screen?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is if you don't show code. If you haven't already, I suggest creating another question with some sample code of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two variants:

1. Replace **window.rootViewController** with your next view
   controller. Do it on AppDelegate class.
2. Present new view controller
   from current root view controller. Do it in your sign up view
   controller.

The lack of the first method is no transaction animation. So second method is preferable.

Comment: not understanding. that is what above tries to do... self.window.rootViewController = navigation where navigation is the navcontroller in which the "newuser" view controller is embedded.  I also tried removing nav and having self.windowRootController =rootController and got same result.  what should I do differently.

Comment: What result you got? Did not understand what problem occurs.

Comment: The existing login screen just stays there and the viewcontroller newuser does not load.